# How can I set the mutable shape of output during making operation in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

During making operation in Tensorflow, I had to set shape of output during registering operation with `REGISTER_OP`.

Specifically as I know, I used `SetShapeFn` for setting the output. However if I can't fix the shape of the output, I have no idea to set the shape of output.

Until now, I set the shape of the output as `UnknownShape` if I can't fix the output shape but I concerned about some disadvantages during run this operation.

Is there any bad effect if I set the output shape as `UnknownShape`?

I want to get some advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some op requires specific input shape, for example, `tf.image.resize_bilinear` requires input shape to be 4 dimension.
if op like this is after your op, an error will occur.

A workaround is that you can use `tf.reshape` just after your op to define specific output shape.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Actually I got no error, so I was curious about `UnknownShape`. Furthermore the operation perform as I intended. Is there any advice about `UnknownShape`?

Comment: It only affect graph definition, nothing wrong in runtime. So feel free to use it.

Comment: Yap! Thanks for reply. ;>